# Attendance tracker: Only count days Absent, Present, Late etc.. from previous days till present

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet that I use an attendance tracker for our business. This sheet reads month tabs and tally's the total Days present, Absent, Late etc..

The issue I am running into is that when someone plans a future time off or prearrange lateness I don't want it to tally that until it becomes the present day.

Essentially it should only tally up the present day and the past.

Thanks for the help.[image]
[image]

In the "Report 2022" tab it shows Employee 15 having 6 Present days and 2 AR days. That totals to 8 "Working days count" , thats not accurate because the 2 AR days didnt happen yet; they are future dates.

If you look in the November tab it is counting the AR for future dates, I only want it to count past and present.

I haven't really came up with an idea, I tried the today function but I don't know exactly the best way to go about it.

Here is the sheet with Dummy employee data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/103srHeFcJXvVKNn3w4ljuxAbnpMMy3YNHS4EJthx1pw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Adding the sheet now, thanks